# Confused about Props and State

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am a beginner at React and i don't understand the idea behind props and state or setState. I have some experience in javascript and node is there something similar on node that can help me understand the idea of props and state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as **React** is concerned, the main idea behind props and state is that props can be passed from outside, whereas the state can only be defined and maintained inside the component itself.

Now, many would argue that the state can be changed from outside of the component, and that can be done by passing some function which updates the state of the component as a prop to another component.

Think of it like this, the state of the component is defined **inside** the component's constructor and can be changed only by calling the `setState` method. The `setState` function can be called when a button is clicked, or a text is entered in an input etc. You can also pass some function which calls `setState` as a prop to a child component and this is the **only** way that the state of the component can be changed from outside of the component (but this is still from a child component, which means that it is still inside the component).

On the other hand, the props can come from **outside** of the component. They are passed down from a parent component and can be both `function`s and `Object`s and primitive values.

So far this is the difference between `state` and `props` in a React component. This difference continues to be the **same** even after adding **redux** in the mix.

Consider redux as a separate place, totally not related to React and the component's `state` and `props`. Now, what redux does, is it defines a central store where all of the data that the application uses is defined/stored. After this store is configured and instantiated, you can access it in your React components by using the `connect` function from the `react-redux` package. By connecting your React components with redux, you can **only** add extra `props` to your components (as I mentioned previously, the state is defined and modified inside the component, and that is why redux injects data and functions as props to your components). After connecting your component to the redux store, you can call functions (called actions) which will modify the redux store and those components that are dependent on the part of the redux store which got modified, will be rerendered using the new data from the redux store.

There are many articles out there which explain the difference between props and state, one of my favorites is this one [props vs state](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/react-props-state-explained-through-darth-vaders-hunt-for-the-rebels-8ee486576492).

Additionally, you can find advice on what's the best way to use redux by the creator of redux himself [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). Even if you are not interested in redux, you can take a look at this article and get further insight into `state` vs `props`.